# Java code (openGL) takes too much memory & causes the app to stop working

Tags: java, performance, opengl, memory, jogl

I run openGL (JOGL 1.0) in Java , and after 2 minutes every now and then , the 
app just stops working , and the windows just freezes :

[image]

Here you can see that javaw.exe take more than **1161536 KB** , I don't think that's normal , right ?

So what causes this ?

Here the heart of the code , the `display()` method :

```
Class Renderer { ...



    public Renderer ()          
    {
        this.addGLEventListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);

        // put the agent in a specific location inside the room
        this.m_firstPersonLocation = new Point3D(750 , 200 , 5000);

        this.m_coordinate1 = new Point3D(1,0,0);
        this.m_coordinate2 = new Point3D(0,1,0);
        this.m_coordinate3 = new Point3D(0,0,1);
        this.m_center = new Point3D(0,0,0);

        m_angleX = m_angleY = m_angleZ = 0;
        m_xx = m_yy = m_zz = 0;

        // sides of the room

        this.m_sides  = ROOM_GREEN;
        this.m_ground = ROOM_BLUE;
        this.m_roof = ROOM_BLUE;

        this.m_insideCubes.add(STATIC_CUBE);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(STATIC_CUBE2);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING_CUBE);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING2);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING3);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING4);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING5);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING6);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING7);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING8);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING9);
        this.m_insideCubes.add(ROTATING10);
    }




    @Override
    public void init (GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
    {

        GL gl = gLDrawable.getGL(); // get the OpenGL graphics context
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);        // get GL Utilities
        gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting

        //  initiate texture

        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        String currentCubeImage = "";

        try 
        {  

            // create the actual room 
            m_cubicRoom = new Cube3D(ROOM_SIZE_X, ROOM_SIZE_Y, ROOM_SIZE_Z , m_sides, m_roof, m_ground);


            /**
             *  creating elements within the 3d-room 
             */

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_3D_SHAPES; ++i)
            {
                // create the elements within 

                currentCubeImage = m_insideCubes.get(i);
                m_cubes.add(new Cube3D(
                        CUBE_SIZE,
                        CUBE_SIZE,
                        CUBE_SIZE
                        ,currentCubeImage,currentCubeImage,currentCubeImage));
            }

        }

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }


        /**
         * Create a cubic room 
         */
        m_cubicRoom.createCube(gl);

        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);


        /**
         * Creating m_cubes
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_3D_SHAPES; ++i)
            m_cubes.get(i).createCube(gl);


        /**
         * Creating the listener 
         */
        ((Component) gLDrawable).addKeyListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable)
    {
        moveFirstPerson();
        checkCameraCollisionWithObject();

        final GL gl = gLDrawable.getGL();
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();


        // the point where it all begins 
        m_center.setPoint(m_firstPersonLocation.getX() - m_coordinate3.getX() , 
                   m_firstPersonLocation.getY() - m_coordinate3.getY() ,
                   m_firstPersonLocation.getZ() - m_coordinate3.getZ());

        // the GLU look-at
        m_glu.gluLookAt(m_firstPersonLocation.getX(),m_firstPersonLocation.getY(),m_firstPersonLocation.getZ(),
                      m_center.getX(),m_center.getY(),m_center.getZ(),
                      m_coordinate2.getX(),m_coordinate2.getY(),m_coordinate2.getZ());

        /**
         * first attache cube 1 (the room itself) - attaching the outer 3D room  
         */

        int shapeNumber = 0;
        gl.glCallList(++shapeNumber);  // cube 1

        /**
         *  attach CUBE 2 - rotating cube 
         */




        /**
         * debug 
         */

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("Camera current location:\n" +
                "\nX location is :" + this.m_firstPersonLocation.getX() +
                "\nY location is :" + this.m_firstPersonLocation.getY() +
                "\nZ location is : " + this.m_firstPersonLocation.getZ());
        System.out.println("***************************");


        if (!collision)
        {
            gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(400.0f, 300.0f, 1300.0f);
//          gl.glRotatef(m_angleX, 4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
//          gl.glRotatef(m_angleY, 0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f);   
//          gl.glRotatef(m_angleZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 42.0f);
            gl.glCallList(++shapeNumber); // cube 2
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        }





        /**
         *  attach CUBE 3 - rotating cube 
         */
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(600.0f, 350.0f, 700.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(m_xx, 24.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(m_yy, 0.0f, 14.0f, 0.0f);  
        gl.glRotatef(m_zz, 0.0f, 0.0f, 14.0f);
        gl.glCallList(++shapeNumber);  // cube 3 
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        /**
         *  attach CUBE 4 - rotating cube 
         */

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(900.0f, 350.0f , 200.0f );
        gl.glRotatef(m_angleX, -2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(m_angleY, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  
        gl.glRotatef(m_angleZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glCallList(++shapeNumber); // cube 4

        m_angleX += 0.15f;
        m_angleY += 0.25f;
        m_angleZ += 0.45f;
        gl.glPopMatrix();


        // more code 
      }
```

Comment: What is the value of NUMBER_OF_3D_SHAPES?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan: It's 15.

Comment: Do you know how to use a profiler? If yes then you can quickkly check what is eating up the memory

Comment: @Juned Ahsan: Can I use it inside the code ?

Comment: @ron A profiler would normally analyze your program externally. I'm sure you can figure it out of you search for one. It's not that complicated.

Comment: There is one called VisualVM, which comes with the jdk. See in your installed jdk bin folder. I believe post jdk 1.5 they started to ship it.

Comment: OpenGL resources created with `glGen*` functions aren't guaranteed to have in-order numbers. The way you make all your glCallList calls is wrong, you should be storing the result of `glGenLists` in an array, and calling `array[shapeNumber++]` to get the list id. Depending on when/how you call `glGenLists`, you could be leaking a ton of client-side memory by re-generating and forgetting about lists.

I'd like to see how you're generating your display lists, and any code that's run every frame that might be calling `glGenLists`

Comment: @RobertRouhani: Okay , now I see the answer I was looking for . I'm regenerating the shapes over and over again ... am I correct ? if so , please post your comment as an answer , so I'd able to choose it as the correct one . I'll check now if you suspicion is indeed correct ... thanks !!!

Comment: @RobertRouhani: Display Lists are part of old OpenGL API before (and including) version 2.x. A peculirarity about those old OpenGL versions is, that object IDs (texture, display list, etc.) may be choosen by the program and there is no requirement to use `glGen…` functions to obtain object IDs.

Comment: @datenwolf wow, never knew that... I dived right into modern OpenGL when I learned it, so I just assumed the older API would act in the same way.

Comment: @RobertRouhani: There have been a lot of improvments to the better in modern OpenGL. The requirement to use IDs generated by the `glGen…` functions is one of them. In OpenGL-4 core keeping around the *glVertexAttribPointer* functions however was stupid. The should have either change their signature to take a *GLintptr* as last parameter and renamed them *glVertexAttribOffset* or removed them alltogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL objects are not garbage collected. In OpenGL version <= 2.1, everytime you call `glNewList(id,…)` or `glBindTexture(id,…); …; glTexImage2D(…)` with a previously unused `id` a new object is created. The old object will linger around and not be garbage collected.

That's most likely your problem: You're probably constantly creating new texture and or display lists without disposing the old ones.

Comment: I've checked now , and I create 14 elements only once , in the `init()` method . So probably the problem occurs in `diplay()` . How can I discard the old ids ?